# Strapi Revision/History Models. How to? How to structure the models?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, strapi

One of my clients wants a history/revision feature in Strapi.

The goal is a wikipedia-like system with published entities such as publications, projects, events etc. which may have relations to one another (many-to-many).

My approach was to copy the model of the entity (eg. publication) and name it "publication-history-entry" with all attributes/fields from the original entity.

However I cannot simply copy relationships without breaking them.

When copying a relation like this it will give me unexpected behaviour, right?

```
"cooperations": {
    "collection": "cooperation",
    "via": "publications",
    "dominant": true
},
```

Further the history entities will have to be comparable with the current entity.
Do you guys have any suggestions in terms of DB model structure to accomplish this, without potentially having corrupted relationships?

Any help is very much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe create a model Revision with a JSON field where you put inside your entire data object (attribues/fields).